# Sequence Numbers with Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the dataset below:

```
tmp = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1, 2, 2, 3),
             cont_date = c("2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01"))
library(lubridate)
tmp$cont_date = ymd(tmp$cont_date)
```

I am probably missing something obvious, but I expected the following code

```
tbl_df(tmp) %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(cont_date) %>% mutate(seqnum = 1:length(id))
```

to create a sequence number of each block of records, which are grouped by id.  Instead, this is what I get:

```
      id  cont_date seqnum
1  1 2015-01-01      1
2  2 2015-01-01      2
3  1 2016-01-01      3
4  3 2016-01-01      4
5  1 2017-01-01      5
6  2 2017-01-01      6
```

I dont want to a sequence number of all records, but for each block.  It looks like the `group_by` portion is being ignored.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting sequences within `id` when I run this. Maybe check in a clean session?

Comment: Or check if you have the latest dplyr from CRAN

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it was; just needed to restart my session.  I don't believe that I have ever had that happen to me before.

Comment: You can get rid of the arrange if you use `row_number(id)` or one of the rank functions

Comment: Unfortunately my answer to the question was deleted, because the solution was found in the form of a comment, but all I needed was a clean session.  Not sure I follow the logic of removing an answer to this post and leaving the question open?